# Laravel public storage return 404 for image

Tags: php, laravel

Following the Laravel docs (I'm using using Laravel in docker using sail) I created a symlink for the storages `php artisan storage:link`. I tried to re-create the links by using the full path starting from root as well.

Then I store a file with

```php
// ...
$filename = 'signatures/signature_' . auth()->user()->id . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $image_type;
Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, $image_base64);
```

After that I am successfully able to open my file from the console:

```
open public/storage/signatures/signature_101-62a876ce68884.png
```

When I try to access if from my url, I get a 404:

```
http://laravel.test/storage/signatures/signature_101-62a876ce68884.png
```

I noticed that by trying to display the image:

```
<img src="{{ url('/storage/' . $clients->signature->filename) }}">
```

Finally I tried

```
rm public/storage
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan storage:link
```

without success

Comment: include public in url as well and then check.

Comment: This does not help. Btw. removing storage does not work as well.

Comment: Do you have enough permission to access data from storage folder? which OS do you use ?

Comment: The public folder has `drwxr-xr-x`. I use macOS

Comment: Solution found by myself - see the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. Laravel advising to use sail in the first place and the documentation does not cover this behaviour.

The symlink must be created in the container!

In the root of the project:

- rm public/storage
- docker exec -it  php artisan storage:link

Comment: The docker command need container name too. In my case `docker exec -it projectname-laravel.test-1 php artisan storage:link`.